# How do I restart the SSH service?

Tags: ssh, services

How do I stop/start ssh? I've tried

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
sudo service ssh restart
sudo restart ssh
```

I get errors every time.

Comment: IMPORTANT - do not install openssh-server  on your local machine (laptop/desktop) unless you wish to permit incoming connections from other remote machines ... you do NOT need this package to ssh to other machines since ubuntu comes with the Client half of this Server

Answer (score 64):

### 15.04 and newer:

Use this command:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

To restart the SSH server/daemon.

Going forward with `systemd` starting with **Ubuntu 15.04**, you now use this syntax to stop, start, or restart services:

```
sudo systemctl <action> <service-name>
```

Comment: Afterwards, check the status of the SSH daemon using `sudo systemctl status ssh`

Comment: On ubuntu 18 I get `Failed to restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.`

Comment: `alias sc='sudo systemctl'` quicker and matches a similar util on Windows. ;-)

Answer (score 19):

Command for restart `ssh service` is:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 15):

### Pre 15.04:

It should be as simple as (tested on a fresh install with openssh-server)

```
sudo stop ssh
sudo start ssh
```

As it leverages [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), this is The Best Way™ to do it, rather than using /etc/init.d/ssh, `service`, or invoking sshd directly. Make sure to run both commands; if you get an error on `stop ssh`, `start ssh` anyway and see what it says—the service could already be stopped.

(I would recommend `stop`/`start` over `restart`, unless you are trying to restart a system remotely. If ssh is already stopped, `restart` will *not* start it.)

If those commands don't work, you are probably either experiencing a bug or have tinkered too far with your system, in which case you at least know what the problem isn't.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/621095/cant-use-start-command-in-15-04

Answer (score 6):

Since Ubuntu 15.04, [Canonical no longer ships upstart by default](https://askubuntu.com/a/621209/8698).
Thus, the commands `start`, `stop` and `restart` are no longer available.

The correct method for restarting the SSH service (or any other service) now is one of the two following commands:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Read also: [Difference between `systemctl` and `service`](https://askubuntu.com/a/903405/566421); [`man service`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/service.8.html); [`man systemctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/systemctl.1.html); [`man reboot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/reboot.8.html); [`man shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/shutdown.8.html).

Answer (score 3):

**On Ubuntu Desktop:**

First check the status of the service:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

[image]

should show: - `Active: active (running)` If it's running there's no need to restart it.
If you still want to restart it, Ubuntu calls the service ssh, not sshd.

```
service ssh restart
```

But if its not Ubuntu Desktop, using CLI:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
sudo service ssh restart
```

The service is also controlled by upstart, and not sysvinit. So you'll find it at /etc/init/ssh.conf instead of /etc/init.d/ssh.

If you want to change some settings (e.g., the listening port, and root login permission) by editing the configuration file via command:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

On Ubuntu desktop, you may use gedit instead of nano:

[image]

Finally apply the changes by restarting or reloading SSH:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

If above still doesn't work then, type this:

```
sudo service ssh stop
sudo service ssh start
```

If all above fails, try restarting your ubuntu system:

```
sudo reboot -f
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the Unknown instance error is because SSH is not running.

Try:

```
ps ax | grep sshd
```

To see if the SSH daemon is running or not, you should see something like:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

In any case, just try any of these:
`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start`
`sudo start ssh`

Answer (score 2):

First check to see if sshd is running using the following:

```
ps -ef | grep sshd
```

You should see something like:

```
root      1234     1  0 12:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

If you do not see a line for `/usr/sbin/sshd -D` then sshd was either never started or has crashed, which will require further troubleshooting to find out why.

If you do see that line, next run this:

```
cat /var/run/sshd.pid
```

This should print the process id of sshd, so in this case you should see:

```
userid@computername:~$ cat /var/run/sshd.pid 
1234
```

If the contents of sshd.pid does not match the process id of the running instance of sshd then something has restarted it incorrectly.  But whatever the details you find here should put you on the right track.  Either it's crashing, being restarted incorrectly, or never being started in the first place.