# Can't Use 'start' command in 15.04

Tags: command-line, services

I used to be able to start and stop processes in Terminal with `sudo start` or `sudo stop`

Example: `sudo start ttyS0`
This would start a getty so I could log in from a serial terminal.
It doesn't work in Ubuntu 15.04. Is there an alternate way to start and stop processes in 15.04?

Comment: Wich getty package?

Answer (score 7):

## The service management system has changed.

Every system management toolset has own utilities.  The utilities that you are used to using are the ones that come with upstart, which are trivial shims for `initctl start` and `initctl stop`.  But this is Ubuntu version 15.  *You aren't using upstart any more.*

You're using systemd, and the service control commands are subcommands of `systemctl` rather than of `initctl`.  So services are started with `systemctl start`, stopped with `systemctl stop`, enabled with `systemctl enable`, disabled with `systemctl disable`, and queried with `systemctl status`.

## Services and service configuration have changed.

You've presumably followed instructions like the *Serial Console How-To* to turn the supplied `/etc/init/tty1.conf` into an `/etc/init/ttyS0.conf`.  This is an upstart configuration file and it will simply be ignored by systemd.  None of what you have learned from there applies to systemd, not even the concept of run levels, which is "obsolete" in the systemd world.

The systemd configuration file for a `getty` on a real terminal device is `/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service`.  This is a *template unit*, parameterized on the name of the serial device file.  So the actual service name to use will be `serial-getty@ttyS0.service`.  You just enable/disable/start/stop it like any other service.

If you want an actual serial *console*, rather than just an ordinary serial terminal, then you don't even do that.  systemd has a mechanism that automatically instantiates `serial-getty@.service` whenever the kernel is told to not have its console on a virtual terminal.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemctl`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- James Hunt and Clint Byrum (2014).  ["Utilities"](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#utilities).  *Upstart Cookbook*.
- Steve Langasek (2015-04-10). [*Serial Console How-To*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto).  Ubuntu.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemd-getty-generator`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-getty-generator.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to start/stop tty service at runtime and just need it to be started during boot phase, then you don't have to worry about learning complicated ***systemd*** and ***systemctl*** things.

You can simply start a ttyS0 port for instance by adding below lines in GRUB2 (or other boot loader).

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"

 #Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
 GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
 GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no -->
 stop=1"
```

I got this done in ubuntu 15.10 server running on a Virtualbox env.

```
[  OK  ] Started Serial Getty on ttyS0. -- started by GRUB2
[  OK  ] Started Getty on tty1. -- started by systemd
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
...
Ubuntu 15.10 server1 ttyS0  -- redirect console to ttyS0, if necessary
```

Comment: this seems to be a comment on the other answer...

Comment: Trying to give an alternative if systemctl and systemd are over-killing the case. And unused instructions are removed according to your comments, thanks!

Comment: And comments from JdeBP doesn't really give a direct answer to the question. I have tried to start a service `root@server1:~# systemctl start ttyS0` but it fails without giving more clue to continue: 
`Failed to start ttyS0.service: Unit ttyS0.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`