# How to restart a process in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: process

Apparently `exec su -l gert -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /data/location/server/process'` method no longer works under Ubuntu 17.04. What is the new method for restarting a process after it dies...

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 17.04 uses systemd for managing processes that previously were managed in Ubuntu by Upstart.

Specifically, the systemd `systemctl` command is now used to start/stop/restart systemd services (e.g., `sudo systemctl start dms3client.service`). The `systemctl` command does a bunch more too.

Here's a great explanation of how to use `systemctl` right here on askbuntu.com: https://askubuntu.com/a/903360/32664.