# sudo service apache2 restart VS sudo systemctl restart apache2

Tags: apache2

I'm a new Linux user, I'm using LAMP in Ubuntu 18.04, both orders run equals in appearance.

What is the difference between the next two commands:

```
sudo service apache2 restart 

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between systemctl and service commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service-commands)

Answer (score 2):

`service` is used when dealing with old system V init scripts and `systemctl` for systemd services, etc. I would suggest not dealing with `service` or system V init scripts anymore, unless it's some legacy application.