# What is the difference in "systemctl restart ssh" and "service ssh restart"?

Tags: debian

I found only [one related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service-commands), but I don't feel the answer to that question helps me, the answers are too generic and broad.

I'm currently on and learning about Debian 11.3. How do I know which command to use in which case?

I don't know what other information I would need to include for this question. I'll update the question if needed.

Comment: One of the quoted code blocks in my answer is literally: `case "${ACTION}" in
  restart|status)
     exec systemctl $sctl_args ${ACTION} ${UNIT}
  ;;` i.e. `systemctl restart ...` is executed by `service ... restart`.

Answer (score 3):

`service ssh restart` is a wrapper around `systemctl restart ssh` -- when you use the `service` command, it runs the `systemctl` command.

The `service` commands were written at a time when it was common for different distributions to have different ways of launching services (aka daemons). The `service` commands didn't care which way things were launched, and it created a uniform way of starting, stopping or restarting services. These days, most systems run `systemd`, which means that `systemctl` is available almost everywhere. It basically doesn't matter which one you use.