# How to reload config after changing /etc/sysctl.d/?

Tags: kernel, configuration

How to reload after changing a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`?

According to `/etc/sysctl.d/README.sysctl`

> After making any changes, please run "service procps force-reload" (or, from
> a Debian package maintainer script "deb-systemd-invoke restart procps.service").

Is the `service` command still "state of the art"?

`man service`

> ```
>    service - run a System V init script
> ```

Now I am unsure. System-V init script ... Wasn't that replaced by systemd long ago?

I use Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be state of the art?

Comment: I updated the question. `man service` ... System-V init script ... Wasn't that replaced by systemd long ago?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between systemctl and service commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service-commands)

Comment: Also the quoted README refers to a systemd service (`procps.service` - Sys-V init  usually don't have the .service extension)

Answer (score 1):

As per [this Redhat document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/working_with_sysctl_and_kernel_tunables):
Execute `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/99-custom.conf` to apply the changes without rebooting.